# How do I show a collection on a JSP page?

Tags: java, jsp, collections, rows

```
Sorry I am really new to this and any help will be appreciated. At the moment the info I have in the below table but i want to pull this info from the collection. Where do I even start.
```

SavingsPlanRates getSavingsPlanRates(SavingsPlanRatesRequest savingsPlanRatesRequest)

/**
* Retrieve the interest tiers of the savings accounts
*/
public static final BancsMessage BANCS_REQ_001870 = new BancsMessage(1870,
new BancsMessageField("Filler1", 10, '_', BancsMessageDataType.INTEGER, 0));

```
/**
 * Returns an entity that contains the interest rates for a flexible savings
 * account
 */
public static final BancsMessage BANCS_RSP_001870_FLEXIBLESAVINGSPRODUCTCOLLECTION = new BancsMessage(1870,
        new BancsMessageField("P200AccountType", 4, '_', BancsMessageDataType.INTEGER, 0),
        new BancsMessageField("P200InterestCat", 4, '_', BancsMessageDataType.INTEGER, 0),
        new BancsMessageField("P200Term", 4, '_', BancsMessageDataType.STRING, 0),
        new BancsMessageField("P200Amt1", 12, '_', BancsMessageDataType.DECIMAL_S2, 0),
        new BancsMessageField("P200TierRate1", 6, '_', BancsMessageDataType.DECIMAL_S3, 0),
        new BancsMessageField("P200Amt2", 12, '_', BancsMessageDataType.DECIMAL_S2, 0),
        new BancsMessageField("P200TierRate2", 6, '_', BancsMessageDataType.DECIMAL_S3, 0),
        new BancsMessageField("P200Amt3", 12, '_', BancsMessageDataType.DECIMAL_S2, 0),
        new BancsMessageField("P200TierRate3", 6, '_', BancsMessageDataType.DECIMAL_S3, 0),
        new BancsMessageField("P200Amt4", 12, '_', BancsMessageDataType.DECIMAL_S2, 0),
        new BancsMessageField("P200TierRate4", 6, '_', BancsMessageDataType.DECIMAL_S3, 0),
        new BancsMessageField("P200MonthlyFee", 11, '_', BancsMessageDataType.DECIMAL_S3, 0));

public static final BancsMessage BANCS_RSP_001870_DAILYSAVINGSPRODUCTCOLLECTION = new BancsMessage(1870,
        new BancsMessageField("P300AccountType", 4, '_', BancsMessageDataType.INTEGER, 0),
        new BancsMessageField("P300InterestCat", 4, '_', BancsMessageDataType.INTEGER, 0),
        new BancsMessageField("P300Term", 4, '_', BancsMessageDataType.STRING, 0),
        new BancsMessageField("P300Amt1", 12, '_', BancsMessageDataType.DECIMAL_S2, 0),
        new BancsMessageField("P300TierRate1", 6, '_', BancsMessageDataType.DECIMAL_S3, 0),
        new BancsMessageField("P300Amt2", 12, '_', BancsMessageDataType.DECIMAL_S2, 0),
        new BancsMessageField("P300TierRate2", 6, '_', BancsMessageDataType.DECIMAL_S3, 0),
        new BancsMessageField("P300Amt3", 12, '_', BancsMessageDataType.DECIMAL_S2, 0),
        new BancsMessageField("P300TierRate3", 6, '_', BancsMessageDataType.DECIMAL_S3, 0),
        new BancsMessageField("P300Amt4", 12, '_', BancsMessageDataType.DECIMAL_S2, 0),
        new BancsMessageField("P300TierRate4", 6, '_', BancsMessageDataType.DECIMAL_S3, 0),
        new BancsMessageField("P300MonthlyFee", 11, '_', BancsMessageDataType.DECIMAL_S3, 0));
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [ask] and reformat your post. Also: "Where do I even start. " - I'd say: start by working through a tutorial on JSPs or any web framework. Once you've got a basic page it should become easier to display the collection.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have worked on Jsp before but very basic things. I understand certain fundamentals. What I need to know is can you give me a basic flow on how I would call the collection. Like an example perhaps? I have googled for a few days and cannot find one. Perhaps I'm looking with the wrong key words.